# NonlinearModelFit doesn't work as a function

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I use a NonlinearFitModel operation for fitting the piecewised data, and then want to use the result of operation as a function. However, it doesn't work. Could anyone please tell me where can be a problem?

Example:

```
data = {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}, {0.3, 34}, {0.4, 38}, {0.5, 42}, {0.6, 
   41}, {0.7, 98}, {0.8, 3}, {0.9, 32}, {1.0, 2}}
fit = Piecewise[{{NonlinearModelFit[Select[data, #[[1]] <= 0.5 &], 
     a + b*M + c*M^0.5, {a, b, c}, M], 
    M <= 0.5}, {NonlinearModelFit[Select[data, #[[1]] > 0.5 &], 
     a + b*M + c*M^0.5, {a, b, c}, M], M > 0.5}}]
fit[2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add M as argument to `fit` and you need to write `Normal[NonlinearModelFit[...]]` to extract the fitted formula.

```
fit[M_] = Piecewise[{{Normal@NonlinearModelFit[Select[data, #[[1]] <= 0.5 &], 
       a + b*M + c*M^0.5, {a, b, c}, M], M <= 0.5}, {Normal@NonlinearModelFit[
    Select[data, #[[1]] > 0.5 &], a + b*M + c*M^0.5, {a, b, c}, M], M > 0.5}}]
fit[2]
```

> -487.93843